# grep and exec issues

Tags: bash, grep, exec

I have a list of urls in a file named list.csv.

I want to grep for the pattern '.php' in the file, and foreach, execute a curl command.

I am trying this:

```
grep '.php' list.csv -exec curl -I {} \;
```

However, I am getting the errors:

```
grep: .php: No such file or directory
grep: curl: No such file or directory
grep: {}: No such file or directory
grep: ;: No such file or directory
```

I am obviously not using grep and exec correctly, but cannot see the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grep '.php' list.csv | xargs curl -I $1

Comment: Thanks, that's the one I'll go with!

Comment: +1 but the xargs call is wrong: `grep '\.php' list.csv | xargs -l1 curl -I `

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax does not make many sense. You are trying to use the `find ... -exec curl -I {} \;` syntax, while it is not possible with `grep`.

Instead, you may use something like:

```
for i in $(grep '.php' list.csv)
do
   curl -I "$i"
done
```

Comment: OK, thanks very much, I just thought there could be a "faster" one-liner with grep and exec.

Answer (score 2):

In one line :)

```
for i in $(grep '.php' list.csv); do curl -I "$i"; done
```